# CMake find specific package of multiple packages with different versions (NCurses)

Tags: c++, cmake, package, ncurses, curses

I currently have a CMake file that finds and links a library (NCurses) to another library

```
...
set(CURSES_NEED_NCURSES TRUE)
find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_library(myLibrary STATIC ${sources})
target_link_libraries(myLibrary ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_options(myLibrary PUBLIC -std=c++20 -Wall -Wconversion)
...
```

This works fine, however unfortunately it is pulling up a different version than I need (5.7 instead of 6.1)

```cpp
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "VERSION: " << NCURSES_VERSION;
}
```

outputs: `VERSION: 5.7`

I do have the desired package installed under: `/usr/local/ncurses/6_1`.
But the logs seem to say it is pulling it from a different location: `Found Curses: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/lib/libncurses.tbd`

How can I specify which of these I want to use?

Comment: You can try setting `Curses_ROOT` variable before finding the package to the root of the library, it might be either an env variable or cmake variable.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this has not resolved the issue.
I've tried both as an env var and set it as a cmake variable (before find_package)

What is strange is that other libraries installed under /usr/local/lib are found properly...

Comment: Did you remove CMakeCache.txt before doing it?

Comment: I did. Although that gave me an idea to investigate the cache! 
It seems I have multiple instances of ncurses everywhere. (I have 6.3 as well!)
I'm not sure how this happened... I might try to see if I can uninstall any if they don't have deps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have figured this out, to anyone else who might come across this.

First I installed the latest version of ncurses (6.3) from here: https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/#downloads-h2
(I downloaded the gzipped tar)

I then went through and deleted all references in my usr/local i could find to ncurses.

I then extracted the tar, and entered the new directory.

I ran just plain `./configure` inside the directory (with no flags).

After that finished, I ran `make`

Then I ran `make install`, after removing symlinks to stop collisions, make install was able to run properly.

Ensure that the CMake variable CURSES_NEED_NCURSES is set to TRUE before finding the package:

```
set(CURSES_NEED_NCURSES TRUE)
find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
```

and it will work perfectly :)